# How to factorize $x^{p^2}-1$?

Tags: factoring, roots-of-unity

**We know** $$x^p−1 = (x-1)(x^{p−1}+x^{p−2}+⋯+x+1).$$
**The question is how to factorize $x^{p^2}-1$?**

**I expanded** $x^{p^2}-1$ as $(x-1)(x^{p^2-1}+x^{p^2-2}+\cdots+x+1)$ following the pattern, but I failed in reducing further the second expression(which is suggested as "can"). Can somebody help?

**Additional context:** This is a  random question from a group chat of people interested in math. This group has a mixed student body in high school and early undergraduate. I searched and used this resource to remind myself how to correctly factorize $x^p-1$: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_of_unity, but I am not able to understand many other contents addressed in this resource such as group, field, etc.

Comment: Is that $(x^p)^2-1$ or $x^{p^2}-1$ ?

Comment: The second expression, sorry, I don't know how to type it like that yet.

Comment: using braces: x^{p^2}

Comment: How do you factorize $x^p-1$ ?

Comment: I fixed your [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @Savio,@J.G, thank you.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe, $x^p-1$ = (x-1)($x^{p-1}+x^{p-2}+\cdots+x+1$)

Comment: For any $n\in\Bbb N$, $$x^n-1=\prod_{d\mid n}\Phi_d(x)$$ where $\Phi_d$ is the $d$-th cyclotomic polynomial.

Comment: @Angia Seng, wow, it seems deeper and more advanced... but it definitely should be useful for people with more knowledge to gain a better understanding of this topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With $y:=x^p$,$$x^{p^2}-1=y^p-1=(y-1)\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}y^k=(x^p-1)\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}x^{kp}=(x-1)\sum_{j=0}^{p-1}x^j\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}x^{kp}.$$

Comment: I was getting confused with the two expressions before,  $$x^{p^2}= x^{p*p},   while 
(x^p)^2={x^p}*{x^p} = x^{p+p}$$ , if I understand correctly this time.

Comment: I am wondering, if not using this method(introducing a new variable y = x^p), is there any way in understanding this equality directly $x^{p^2}-1=(x^p-1)\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}x^{kp}$?

Comment: I may figure it out... It really depends on the understanding of the expression $x^{p^2}$ = $x^{p*p}$ = $x^p*x^p*\cdots*x^p$ (repeated multiplication of $x^p$ by itself p times). Then, the formula follows the expansion of $x^p-1$.

Answer (score 2):

$$(x - 1) \frac{x^p - 1}{x-1} \frac{x^{p^2} - 1}{x^p-1}$$

Comment: How does this expression help the factorization?

Comment: This expression shows it factorises as$$(x-1)(1+x+\dots+x^p)(1+x^p+\dots+x^{p^2})$$

Comment: Yes, it suggests us to first factor out x-1, then factor out $x^p-1$. But, it seems that it still leaves a problem unsolved, like after factoring out the first two expressions, how to get the third expression? (using the method J.G. suggested) BTW, is the final expression equal to (x-1)($1+x+\cdots+x^p$)($1+x^p+x^{2p}+\cdots+x^{p(p-2)}+x^{p(p-1)}$)?

Comment: It doesn't leave the problem unsolved. These are the 3 irreducible factors. If you know how to expand (x^n - 1)/(x - 1) you shouldn't have any trouble expanding (x^n^r - 1)/(x - 1) in fact you have done it correctly in your comment

Comment: I know how to factorize $x^p-1$, but I had trouble before in expanding  $x^{p^2}-1$ (due to superficial understanding).  After my confusion being cleared, I started to understand better the expression you left as an answer. Your comments made me start thinking about working with any "r" ($x^{p^r}-1$). I worked on r=3 and had no trouble. J.G.'s method helps me work through and understand the general case "r". Thank you, guys.

Comment: np, Glad to help!